# No header on last page, wrong page numbers: "Page 3 of 1" with eqexam

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am using the [`eqexam`](https://ctan.org/pkg/eqexam?lang=en) package to create multiple choice test. It usually works fine.

For some reason however with last exam created it does not have footer on the very last page, and the totals for page numbers are wrong: I have for example "- Page 3 of 1 -" in header, instead of correct "- Page 3 of 4 -".

**Edit:** what is strange I have just noticed that the bug exists only in no `proofing` and with `nosolutions` as options to `eqexam` package.  Which means that it works when printing solution, but not when printing actual exam blank.

How to debug this issue, and fix it? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Could you try to make an MWE for this? Start with the full exam and step by step remove as much content as possible until the issue disappears, then post the smallest document that still shows the issue in your question.

Comment: Did you latex at least twice your document? If the problem then still exists please provide your example. Be sure to have the latest version from CTAN.

Answer (score 1):

Here a demo example done with the `nosolutions` option and the `answerkey` and `proofing` option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[
%proofing
%nosolutions,   % suppresses the solutions
answerkey       % puts the solutions right after the problem
]{eqexam}

\examNum{1}
\subject[MyAbbr]{My Course Subject}
\title[HW\nExam]{Homework \#\nExam}
\author{Dr.\ John Doe}
\date{Summer 2018}
\duedate{2018/07/28}
\keywords{Homework due \theduedate}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{exam}{HW\nExam}
\begin{instructions}[Solutions]
Instructions Blablabla
\end{instructions}

\begin{eqComments}[Comments for whatever]
Comments Blablabla
\end{eqComments}

\begin{problem}[4]
Problem BLABLAB
\begin{solution}
Solution BLABLA
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\newpage

\begin{problem}[3]
Problem BLABLAB
\begin{solution}
Solution BLABLA
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\newpage

\begin{problem}[2]
Problem BLABLAB
\begin{solution}
Solution BLABLA
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\newpage

\begin{problem}[4]
Problem BLABLAB
\begin{solution}
Solution BLABLA
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\newpage

\begin{problem}[3]
Problem BLABLAB
\begin{solution}
Solution BLABLA
\end{solution}
\end{problem}
\end{exam}
\end{document}
```

This screenshot results from the `answerkey` option:
[image]

This screenshot results from the `nosolutions` option:
[image]

This screenshot results from the `proofing` option:

[image]

Hope this will help. In any other case, please provide your example file.

**Note:** Always latex the tex file at least twice!

**Sidenote:** This package is only available within the MiKTeX distribution and not within the TeXLive distribution, but at least kept updated on CTAN. However for TeXLive users: it is available through the TeXLive **Contribution**. One could setup a second repository to the **TLCONTRIB** server within the TeXLive-Manager and therefrom get a regular update if wanted.

See this link [Install TLContrib](https://www.preining.info/blog/2017/07/tlcontrib-renewed/) to get information how to get the **TLCONTRIB** on start within the TeXLive-Manager.